# How can I timestamp messages in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

Disclaimer: I know absolutely nothing about nifi.

I need to receive messages from the `ListenHTTP` processor, and then convert each message into a timestamped json message.

So, say I receive the message `hello world` at 5 am. It should transform it into `{"timestamp": "5 am", "message":"hello world"}`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each flowfile has *attributes*, which are pieces of metadata stored in key/value pairs in memory (available for rapid read/write). When any operation occurs, pieces of metadata get written by the NiFi framework, both to the *provenance* events related to the flowfile, and sometimes to the flowfile itself. For example, if `ListenHTTP` is the first processor in the flow, any flowfile that enters the flow will have an attribute `entryDate` with the value of the time it originated in the format `Thu Jan 24 15:53:52 PST 2019`. You can read and write these attributes with a variety of processors (i.e. `UpdateAttribute`, `RouteOnAttribute`, etc.).

For your use case, you could a `ReplaceText` processor immediately following the `ListenHTTP` processor with a search value of `(?s)(^.*$)` (the entire flowfile content, or "what you received via the HTTP call") and a replacement value of `{"timestamp_now":"${now():format('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z')}", "timestamp_ed": "${entryDate:format('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z')}", "message":"$1"}`.

The example above provides two options:

1. The `entryDate` is when the flowfile came into existence via the `ListenHTTP` processor
2. The `now()` function gets the current timestamp in milliseconds since the epoch

Those two values can differ slightly based on performance/queuing/etc. In my simple example, they were 2 milliseconds apart. You can format them using the `format()` method and the normal [Java time format syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), so you could get "5 am" for example by using `h a` (full example: `now():format('h a'):toLower()`).

**Example**

- `ListenHTTP` running on port `9999` with path `contentListener`
- `ReplaceText` as above
- `LogAttribute` with log payload `true`

[image: NiFi flow on canvas and terminal showing log and curl command]

Curl command: `curl -d "helloworld" -X POST http://localhost:9999/contentListener`

Example output:

```
2019-01-24 16:04:44,529 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=8246b0a0-0168-1000-7254-2c2e43d136a7] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=5e1c6d12-298d-4d9c-9fcb-108c208580fa,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1548374015429-1, container=default, section=1], offset=3424, length=122],offset=0,name=5e1c6d12-298d-4d9c-9fcb-108c208580fa,size=122]
--------------------------------------------------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
    Value: 'Thu Jan 24 16:04:44 PST 2019'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
    Value: 'Thu Jan 24 16:04:44 PST 2019'
Key: 'fileSize'
    Value: '122'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'filename'
    Value: '5e1c6d12-298d-4d9c-9fcb-108c208580fa'
Key: 'path'
    Value: './'
Key: 'restlistener.remote.source.host'
    Value: '127.0.0.1'
Key: 'restlistener.remote.user.dn'
    Value: 'none'
Key: 'restlistener.request.uri'
    Value: '/contentListener'
Key: 'uuid'
    Value: '5e1c6d12-298d-4d9c-9fcb-108c208580fa'
--------------------------------------------------
{"timestamp_now":"2019-01-24 16:04:44.518 -0800", "timestamp_ed": "2019-01-24 16:04:44.516 -0800", "message":"helloworld"}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I added an `ExecuteScript` processor with this code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.time.LocalDateTime

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile)return
def text = ''
// Cast a closure with an inputStream parameter to InputStreamCallback
session.read(flowFile, {inputStream ->
  text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
  // Do something with text here
} as InputStreamCallback)


def outputMessage = '{\"timestamp\":\"' + LocalDateTime.now().toString() + '\", \"message:\":\"' + text + '\"}'

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
  text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
  outputStream.write(outputMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

and it worked.